# Unable to rewrite a particular url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm setting up my new computer and seem to have an odd problem with one of my websites. Any URL that begins with /api should be redirected to api.php in the document root. The .htaccess file below worked on my old machine but doesn't on the new one...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api* /api.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

I get a 404 when accessing /api/v1/articles. I have mod_rewrite enabled, I can browse directly to the api.php file and it works if I use the .htaccess example below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wapi* /api.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

So it seems like there is only ever a problem redirecting /api. What could be causing this?!

(running Apache on Ubuntu 13.04 btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a slash to your rule and *make sure `Multiviews` is OFF*:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteRule ^api/ /api.php [L]
```

`Multiviews` is part of mod_negotiation, and when it's turned on (which it sometimes is by default), it will supercede rewrite rules because it comes before mod_rewrite in the URL processing pipeline. If it sees a request `/api` and sees that there is a file called `/api.php`, it assumes you meant `/api.php` instead of a fake directory `/api/`.

Comment: Turning off multiviews fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api(?!\.php).*$ /api.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: No that didn't do it but again if I add a "w" before "api" it works fine

Comment: Most likely because of `MultiViews` turned on Apache was automatically loading `api.php` ignoring your rewrite rule altogether.